# Convert a bigint to a string or integer in Go

Tags: string, go, integer, bigint

How do one convert a big int to a string (or integer) in Golang?

```
bigint := big.NewInt(123) //This is what I have
bigstr = "123" //This is what I want
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment pst. After hours of searching, I would say that the documentation is not great on bigints. For instance, I still couldn't figure out for the life of me how to convert from a string to a bigint.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use the `String` method : http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.String

```
bigint := big.NewInt(123)
bigstr := bigint.String()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, cyberdelia. Should I make a new question, or can I ask you how to convert the other way around: from a string to a bigint? (Again, I couldn't find the answer anywhere).

Comment: @BurntSushi5 - Thank you so much! That is a great little string to big.Int example: bigint.SetString("123", 10)

Answer (score 4):

You asked how to convert a bigInt to string or to int, the accepted answer explains only how to convert to string.

So you have your `bigint := big.NewInt(123)`

---

You can convert your bigInt to integer in two possible ways:

- using [.Int64()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Int64). With `yourInt := bigint.Int64()`
- using [.Uint64()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Uint64). With `yourUint := bigint.Uint64()`

The reason for two methods is that uint holds 2 time bigger numbers, and sometimes you know that the answer is positive. Beware that if the number is bigger than the maximum possible for int64/uint64:

> If x cannot be represented in an int64, the result is undefined.

---

And for completeness, to convert to string, just use [.String()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.String) `bigstr := bigint.String()`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
bigint := big.NewInt(1231231231231)
bigstr := fmt.Sprint(bigint)
```

Comment: Calling `bigint.String()` directly (instead of via interface{} of fmt) is simpler and more efficient. The only reason to use the `fmt` package for this is if you wanted to make use of special formatting.

Comment: I used the bigint.String() in a really big int and obtained something like 1.2123423534546e308