# How to parse long hexadecimal string into uint

Tags: go

I'm pulling in data that is in long hexadecimal string form which I need to convert into decimal notation, truncate 18 decimal places, and then serve up in JSON.

For example I may have the hex string:

```
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3c21bcecceda1000000"
```

At first I was attempting to use `ParseUint()`, however since the highest it supports is `int64`, my number ends up being way too big.

This example after conversion and truncation results in 10^6.
However there are instances where this number can be up to 10^12 (meaning pre truncation 10^30!).

What is the best strategy to attack this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [math/big](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big) for working with numbers larger than 64 bits.

From the [`Int.SetString`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#example_Int_SetString) example:

```
s := "d3c21bcecceda1000000"
i := new(big.Int)
i.SetString(s, 16)
fmt.Println(i)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vf31ce93vA

The `math/big` types also support the `encoding.TextMarshaler` and `fmt.Scanner` interfaces.

For example

```
i := new(big.Int)
fmt.Sscan("0x000000d3c21bcecceda1000000", i)
```

Or

```
i := new(big.Int)
fmt.Sscanf("0x000000d3c21bcecceda1000000", "0x%x", i)
```

Comment: SetString gets String and  Base (in this case hexadecimal is 16 )

Answer (score 1):

If you are **okay with truncating** the value to Uint64. Here is an [answer from user @salvador-dali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30432177/13729454) in [Convert a bigint to a string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810948/convert-a-bigint-to-a-string-in-go)

> You asked how to convert a bigInt to string or to int, the accepted
> answer explains only how to convert to string. So you have your bigint
> := big.NewInt(123) You can convert your bigInt to integer in two
> possible ways:
>
> - `using .Int64(). With yourInt := bigint.Int64()`
> - `using .Uint64(). With yourUint := bigint.Uint64()`
>
> The reason for two methods is that uint
> holds 2 time bigger numbers, and sometimes you know that the answer is
> positive. Beware that if the number is bigger than the maximum
> possible for int64/uint64:
>
> If x cannot be represented in an int64, the result is undefined.
>
> And for completeness, to convert to string, just use .String() bigstr
> := bigint.String()

To jump off of that. I had trouble using these steps for you big hex number. I included my own big hex number so if you want to take a go. Here is a [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/h8TQf5gEUtv) to show how it works. If you want to convert from a long hexadecimal string to Uint. You would have to do:

- `String -> bigint -> uint64`

As mentioned you can do all of this with the [`math/big`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big) package.

```
bighex := "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3c21bcecceda1000000"
bi := new(big.Int) // create new *big.Int object (allocates the memory for it)

bi.SetString(bighex, 16) // convert to *big.Int from base 16 string

bigUint := bi.Uint64() // Will truncate big.Int to only 64 bytes (returns a Uint64 type)
```

You can't go from a long hexadecimal string to Uint directly, because you would get an overflow error, where the transformed string is too large to fit in a Uint64 (as you might have experienced).