# Golang vs Python - Hex String to Int

Tags: python, go, type-conversion, hex

I have a hex string:

```
n = "0xd458985bc81e284609dd69267c73b8464e1795d5b91ce6ed8871ecbc5b6ec4d1"
```

that I can convert to an int in python by using:

```
mynum = int(n,16)
```

and I get the long number: `96046857981227695367604088053507399752198003710848334588478940192231467697361`

Now how would I do this in Golang?

Comment: What do you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the binary.BigEndian.Uint64()  and then also the hex.DecodeString(), but both just give me wrong numbers

Comment: Questions seeking coding help _must_ include the current attempt, and explain the current output, and what is expected.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47315683/13860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question (though similar to another that Flimzy found). The main problem is that the built-in integers only go up to 64 bits in Go but you can use the math/big package.

```
fmt.Println(new(big.Int).SetString("0xd458985bc81e284609dd69267c73b8464e1795d5b91ce6ed8871ecbc5b6ec4d1", 0))
```

If you don't have a leading 0x then use 16 as the base:

```
fmt.Println(new(big.Int).SetString("d458985bc81e284609dd69267c73b8464e1795d5b91ce6ed8871ecbc5b6ec4d1", 16))
```