# how Convert 0xffffffff to -1 in go

Tags: string, go

I have the following string, I want to convert it to a negative number in parentheses, can someone tell me how to do it in golang?

```
0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff -> (-1)
0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe -> (-2)
```

I know there are some similar looking answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315683/how-to-parse-long-hexadecimal-string-into-uint), but this is not what I want.

Comment: The linked answer does solve your issue. Admittedly, it's not very conspicuous how so. The mystery is solved by carefully looking at JimB's example and at the `big.Int.SetString` docs, which say that for bases other than 0, the prefix must be stripped.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315683/how-to-parse-long-hexadecimal-string-into-uint) that you've linked you can do the following:

```golang
func main() {
    slice := []string{
        "0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
        "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe",
    }

    for _, s := range slice {
        s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, "0x")

        i := &big.Int{}
        i, _ = i.SetString(s, 16)
        s = fmt.Sprintf("(%d)", i.Int64())

        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

// outputs:
// (-1)
// (-2)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/l9WJ_KwsYu-