# How to convert a uint64 to big.Int in golang?

Tags: go, type-conversion, biginteger

I was wondering how can I convert a `uint64` to `big.Int` in golang? the shortest way.

I have tried `new(big.Int).SetInt64(int64(a uint64 number))`.

I don't like it cause it's long, too much nested conversions and I'd rather use a built-in function if it exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a bigint to a string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810948/convert-a-bigint-to-a-string-in-go)

Comment: Converting the `uint64` to `int64` is going to give you the wrong value if it's greater than `1<<63 - 1`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shortest and safest would be to use the [`Int.SetUint64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetUint64) method:

```
var x uint64 = 10

i := new(big.Int).SetUint64(x)

fmt.Println(i) // Prints 10
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3PYPK4lpCx1).

Care should be taken when manually converting `uint64` to `int64` (as in your example), as overflow might happen which you won't be notified about, but you will end up with a negative value.

If you can be sure the value fits into an `int64`, using the [`big.NewInt()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt) function is shorter:

```
i := big.NewInt(int64(x))
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N1HytzW4faw).

Comment: Thanks! somehow I missed the SetUint64 method