# Go: convert big.Int to regular integer (int, int32, int64)

Tags: go, numeric, biginteger

I assumed this would be a simple issue with abundant answers on the Internet.  But that does not appear to be the case.

I need to convert a Go `big.Int` into a regular integer (e.g., `int`, `int32`, or `int64`).  But there appears to be no straightforward way to do this.

I've tried `int(bigVal)`, `int32(bigVal)`, and `int64(bigVal)`, but they give the error `cannot convert bigVal(variable of type big.Int) to type x` (where x is either `int`, `int32` or `int64`).

I'm finding myself frustrated over how Go makes handling big numbers so complicated (in contrast to the relative ease of, say, C#/.NET's `System.Numerics.BigInteger`).  How do I accomplish this, something that should a trivially easy task?

Comment: Just asking: You are aware of the implications, right? Bigint Range is way larger than e.g. int range.

Comment: `int32(bigVal.Int64())`? pretty trivial imho.

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl yes I am aware of the implications, but there is no risk of overflow because I am using `Mod` on the number before I try to convert it.

Comment: Have you tried theBigInt.Int()? I remember slt. I am not that familiar with Go but i once read the docs.

Comment: Found it : [Convert a bigint to a string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810948/convert-a-bigint-to-a-string-in-go) Inside the question OP also asks for int conversion.

Comment: Would consulting the documentation of math/big.Int be an option?

Answer (score 0):

@Eldar was correct.  Thank you!  `big.Int` has an instance-level method called `Int64()` that returns the 64-bit integer representation of the value (or `undefined` if it cannot be represented as such).

I merely needed to wrap it woth`int32()` to get the desired result:

`int32(bigVal.Int64())`

Comment: Int64() doesn't "return `undefined`" in the sense of returning _a value that identifies that the value is `undefined`_.  "undefined" in this context is not the same as, say, "NaN", in the context of a float, for example. 
 Rather, the return value being "undefined" is a warning that there is _no contract or specification for what is returned in that case_; your code should not rely on that the current implementation happens to return in such cases (i.e. always the lowest 64 bits of the value).  It could change in the future, e.g. to return 0 or -1 etc for some reason (e.g. efficiency).